# probability intersection is equal to a number. don't know why the solution is like this.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question that says

> $A$ and $B$ are events with $P(A) = .25$ and $P(B) = .4$. Under the given conditions, find these probabilities.

8) $A$ and $B$ are independent.
 e) $P(A \cap B^c)$.
 This I understand is $.25 \cdot (1-.4) = .15$.

f) $P(A \cup B^c)$.
 This I understand is $.25 + .6 - (.25 \cdot .6) = .7$.

10) $P(A \cap B) = .2$.
 e) $P(A \cap B^c)$
 Then it says: $P(A) -  P(A \cap B) = .05$.
 But how did he derive that equation?

f) $P(A \cup B^c) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B^c) = .8$.
 I used the same equation in 8.f and it came out as $.7$.

Can someone explain these last two problems? (10.e, 10.f)

It seems those two should be the same as 8.e, 10.f, I'm not sure what I'm missing. I reviewed the formulas for union and intersection and I still can't see why.

Comment: Please double check your post. I think there are several typos. Also, please use MathJax. There is a detailed tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to recall the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). $B$ and $B^c$ form a partition of the sample space. Then by the law of total probability
$$P(A) = P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c).$$

Rearranging gives you what you want: $P(A\cap B^c) = P(A)-P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 3):

You have one answer explaining how you should do question 10.
Here is why you can't do it the way you were trying to do it:

The formulas you used for 8 (e) and (f) are just for the case where the events are independent. Since 8 says "$A$ and $B$ are independent," you can use those formulas in that problem.

But 10 does not say "independent"; in fact, it specifies a probability $P(A\cap B)=0.2$ that *contradicts* the possibility that $A$ and $B$ could be independent. The formulas for independent variables don't work in that case.

Try to use the intersection formula
to calculate what $P(A\cap B)$ "should" be equal to,
and see if it's consistent with what problem 10 told you.